# Timezone to current time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone

User model has time_zone, which stores say "Pacific Time (US & Canada)".

Scenario: 
1. Current_user lives in Japan timezone
2. Current_user is viewing profile of John who lives in "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
3. On John's profile, I need to show local time at "Pacific Time (US & Canada)" as 10:01 am

What I did?
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new(@user.time_zone).now returns something like 2011-09-21 10:01:56 UTC

Questions:
1. How to do I convert this to 10:01 am?
2. Why is it UTC?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set TimeZone, you need to use

```
Time.zone= @user.time_zone
```

You may want to set this in :before_filter in `application.rb`

OTOH, you can use `use_zone` method with a block

```
Time.use_zone(@user.time_zone) do
  #.... This code will run as if you were in @user.time_zone
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
Time.zone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'
```

to get the local time

```
Time.zone.now      #=> Wed, 21 Sep 2011 02:25:08 PDT -07:00
```

to get 10:00 am/pm

```
Time.zone.now.strftime("%I:%M %p")   #=> 02:25 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

Try smth like this, in you User controller:

```
def show
  @user = find(params[:id])
  Time.zone = @user.time_zone
end
```

To change format:

```
 Time.now.strftime("at %I:%M%p")
```

Answer (score 0):

The ideal way to handle with time is save the data in UTC format in the back end, this will make the conversion process simple.

As Chandra Patni mentioned above, you may use those methods for conversion.

To display the time object in formatted string you may use rails strftime method, http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/strftime